# MVC4 Custom Login Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need some help with some MVC stuff.  I'm trying to update some legacy code I inherited, and am an absolute n00b with web stuff.  This same exact code works on the installed version of the site, but will not work correctly here.

The Index.chtml file is:

```
@model QspAudits.Models.LoginModel
@{
    Layout = null;
    // Unimportant viewbag stuff.  Can post if needed.
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Site | @ViewBag.Title</title>
        @Styles.Render("http://hotline.rimg.net/qspaudits/Content/css/qsp.css")
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitenter(myfield, e) {
                var keycode;
                if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
                else if (e) keycode = e.which;
                else return true;
                if (keycode == 13) {
                    $("#FormLogin").submit();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.login_btn').click(function () {
                    $(this).closest('form').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body id="@ViewBag.BodyID" class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "FormLogin"}))
    {
        <div id="loginBox" class="login">
            <div class="loginForm">
                <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/samsclub_medlogo.png")" class="identity"/>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Site</h2>
                <label>Login</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.username, new { @class = "TextBox", @autofocus=""})
                <label>Password</label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.password, new { @class = "PasswordBox", @onkeypress = "return submitenter(this,event)" })
                <div id="login_btn" class="login_btn"></div>     <span>@Model.message</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The LoginController.cs looks like:

```
namespace QspAudits.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private QspAuditsEntities db = new QspAuditsEntities();
        private BT8_GCEntities bt_db = new BT8_GCEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.bodyID = "login";
            LoginModel log = new LoginModel();
            log.message = "";
            return View(log);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel formResult)
        {
            UserLogin_Result log = db.UserLogin(formResult.username).FirstOrDefault();
            if (log != null && formResult.password != null)
            {
                int pass;
                if (Int32.TryParse(log.password.ToString(), out pass) == true || log.validation == 1)
                {
                    int dbPass = (log.validation == 3 ? pass : Common.MD5Hash(formResult.password));
                    if (dbPass == (int)log.password) //use real valid code
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(log.user_id.ToString() + "|" + log.full_name + "|" + (log.validation == 1 ? "1" : "3"), false);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
            formResult.password = "";
            formResult.message = "Incorrect Username/Password";
            return View(formResult);
        }

        public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code to test (through VS2012), the only breakpoint that ever gets hit is in the [HttpGet] block.  The strangeness is that it hits the [HttpGet] block breakpoint twice.  The [HttpPost] block never gets touched.

This code is running on the live server, so it's got to be something stupid simple I'm missing.

Comment: What is the point of this. Your POST method as a `return RedirectToAction()` and ajax calls do not redirect. Just delete all your  pointless scripts an use `<input type="submit" ../>` to do a normal submit

Comment: Okay, so, that's a lot of verbage, but I can't tell that it has anything to do with anything.  How would changing/eliminating the ajax stuff affect the return result of a method that never gets called?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the script is just unnecessary. Why not just delete it and use a submit button?

Comment: So, no clue as to why the code doesn't actually do what it's supposed to, just a comment on the previous devs coding technique?